# Android Firebase Query returning nothing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Above is my firebase database:

```
-Ideas
  --Key generated by firebase
    --uid
    --name
    --date
    --title
```

Now I want to get all the ideas generated by a particular uid and attach the query to the recycler. Following is my query and adapter but it returns nothing.

```
    DatabaseReference myIdeasReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    final Query myideas =myIdeasReference.child("Ideas")orderByKey().equalTo("userUid",userUid);
    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Idea, IdeaHolder>(Idea.class, R.layout.listview_feed, IdeaHolder.class, myideas) {
        @Override
        public void populateViewHolder(IdeaHolder IdeaViewHolder, final Idea ideaObject, int position) {
            int voteCountint = ideaObject.getvoteCount();
            String voteCount = Integer.toString(voteCountint);
            int flagCountint = ideaObject.getflagCount();
            String flagCount = Integer.toString(flagCountint);
            String title = ideaObject.gettitle();
            String body = ideaObject.getBody();
            String postDate = ideaObject.getPostDate();
            String mfullName = ideaObject.getfullName();
            //pass values :key, Ideauid and Userid to setbutton method in ideaviewholder class
            DatabaseReference idearef = getRef(position);//get the database reference of the object at selected position
            final String key = idearef.getKey();//get key of the idea reference to get the location later in mvote and mflag
            String ideaUid = ideaObject.getuid();
```

P.S. I also tried the following query:

```
     final Query myideas = myIdeasReference.child("Ideas").orderByValue().equalTo("userUid",userUid);
```

but then also nothing was  displayed.

Answer (score 0):

try with this, this should work for you

```
myideas = myIdeasReference.child("Ideas").orderByChild("userUid").equalTo(userUid);
```